# How can I print tuple nested in list in c#?

Tags: c#, list, dictionary, tuples

I have a function to fill a `List` which contains `Tuple`. It takes a dictionary as parameter and fills the list.

I need this to assign numerical values to text values.

For the sake of clearance;

I have an attribute section which includes let's say;

Attribute: Overcast

Text values for overcast: sunny, rainy, foggy etc.

Attribute: Temperature

Text values for it: hot, cold, mild

`List` has datas as attribute, value as text and value as number.

And I have data section. Which has values like "sunny, cold", "sunny, hot" etc.

My aim is to assign numbers and express data like "1,2", "1,3" and so on.
To achieve that I wrote a function.

```
public List<Tuple<string, string, int>> SetNumAttrb(Dictionary<string, string[]> dic)
    {
        List<Tuple<string, string, int>> attNumNom = new List<Tuple<string, string, int>>();
        int ctrl = 1;
        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string[]> kvp in dic)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < kvp.Value.Length; i++)
            {
                attNumNom.Add(Tuple.Create<string, string, int>(kvp.Key, dic[kvp.Key][i], ctrl));
                ctrl++;
            }
        }
        return attNumNom;
    }
```

Now I need to print this to check if it is working correctly and I am going to need to access its content. How can I do that?

Comment: I suppose the Visual Studio Locals window is out of the question?

Comment: The nice thing about `Tuple.Create` is that you can leave out the generic arguments, so in your case you could do just `Tuple.Create(kvp.Key, dic[kvp.Key][i], ctrl)` as the argument to the `Add` method.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen oh I didn't know that. Thank you :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's pretty straightforward. Just iterate over the list and print the contents of the tuple.

```
List<Tuple<string, string, int>> list = SetNumAttrb(dict);

foreach (var tuple in list)
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0} - {1} - {2}", tuple.Item1, tuple.Item2, tuple.Item3.ToString());
}
```

Comment: While `Console.WriteLine` has built-in support for this syntax, you could also use interpolated strings, as in `Console.WriteLine($"{tuple.Item1} - {tuple.Item2} - {tuple.Item3}");` (note the `$` character).

Comment: Understood. Thank you very much again. Important thing for me right now is to access individual items in list.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen Note that syntax only works if you are using C#6.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I misunderstand, but if you use:

```
Console.WriteLine(string.Join("\r\n", attNumNom));
```

you will print each `List<>` item, separated by CR LF (newlines).

Since `Tuple<,,>` overrides `ToString()`, that should be quite readable.

Comment: fyi, [`Environment.NewLine`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.newline) reflects newlines depending on your environment :)

Comment: That could work too for printing but I'll need to access individual elements of tuple so I am going with the answer with foreach(var tuple in list). Thank you anyway :)

Comment: A very interesting method though. Definitely going to try this :)